# I have an issue with collecting results from a SOCKET parallelization in R, this is the first time that I am parallelizing on multiple datasets

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

```
# Trying to backend with SOCKET

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())  # cores
registerDoParallel(cl)  # parallel backend

# I need multiple parameters

param1_values <- list(meta.mix[[8]], meta.mix[[17]], meta.mix[[26]], meta.mix[[35]])
param2_values <-  list(meta.mix[[9]], meta.mix[[18]], meta.mix[[27]], meta.mix[[36]])
n_rows =  nrow(X)
n_cols=  ncol(X)

param_grid <- expand.grid(param1 = param1_values, param2 = param2_values)

# Definisci i tuoi dataset e le liste dei CpG

dataset_list <- clean.list

# cpg_list is the same

# Parallel function

system.time(result_list <- foreach(i = 1:length(dataset_list), .combine = "c") %dopar% {
par_correlation_cpg(
mdpat = param_grid[i, "param1"],
mdpat_count = param_grid[i, "param2"],
cols  = n_cols,
rows = n_rows,
X = dataset_list[[i]],
cpg_list = cpg_list)

}

)

# stop backend

stopCluster(cl)
```

The function works correctly and does its job, but results are saved in weird "chinese boxes" listed together and not in one list per process in parallel. Is there something to improve how results could be saved?
Thank you :)